# How to configure libinput on alpine linux?

Tags: wayland, alpine-linux, libinput, sway

For test purposes I installed alpine on my laptop. (It contains pretty much only the minimal default packages and wayland/sway.)

When I try to run `sway` everything looks fine, but mouse and keyboard do not work. sway uses wayland which uses libinput. Therefore I tried `libinput list-devices` which does not give any output, which explains the behavior of sway.

Any idea why `libinput` does not recognize any input devices?

Do I need to configure libinput in any way? Do I maybe miss some additional package?

(Any hint to suitable documentation would be great, too.)

---

Just double checked it again: if I boot the install image of arch linux, libinput lists all devices fine. If I boot from the alpine image, the output is emtpty. (In both cases `/var/input/event*` is present.)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which documentation gives details but if you were to try and compile `libinput` on Alpine linux you would notice that it requires `udev`. `udev` has been borged by `systemd` but the `eudev` project (Gentoo to the rescue) will provide what you need. To begin you must install `eudev` and start the `udev` service (and you might want to add it to the default runlevel):

```
/etc/init.d/udev start
```

Now udev is ready and listening but does not know about any input devices. Check to see if you have the appropriate udev rules file, it should be called `80-libinput-device-groups.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d` or `/lib/udev/rules.d` this file is **very important**!! Now trigger those rules by receiving events from the kernel with `udevadm`:

```
udevadm trigger
```

There is a file in `/etc/init.d` called `udev-trigger`... this is probably related somehow. Now to see a list of devices:

```
libinput list-devices
```

You should see a list of devices.